# Get category_id from url and send it to php via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page `filter.php?category_id=1`. It comes from a index.php `<a href="filter.php?category_id=<?php echo $category_id; ?>">` I try to send `category_id` to file fetch_data.php.

**filter.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data(1);

    function filter_data(page)
    {
        //$("#preloader").show();
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var filter_category = get_filter('filter_category');
        var filter_material = get_filter('filter_material');
        var filter_source_light = get_filter('filter_source_light');
        var filter_dimming_options = get_filter('filter_dimming_options');
        var filter_color_temperature = get_filter('filter_color_temperature');
        var filter_degree_tightness = get_filter('filter_degree_tightness');
        
        $.ajax({
            //url:"fetch_data.php",
            url:'fetch_data.php?category_id=<?php echo $_GET['category_id']; ?>',
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, filter_category:filter_category, filter_material:filter_material, filter_source_light:filter_source_light, filter_dimming_options:filter_dimming_options, filter_color_temperature:filter_color_temperature, filter_degree_tightness:filter_degree_tightness, page:page},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);       
            }
        });
    }
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
//$category_id = "1";

$category_id = $_GET['$category_id'] ?? '';

if(isset($_POST["action"])) {
    
    $sql1 = "SELECT * ";
    $sql1 .= "FROM photographs ";
    $sql1 .= "WHERE category_id='" . $database->escape_string($category_id) . "' ";
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I set `$category_id = "1"; or "2"` everything works

Comment: You are using `POST` in ajax and getting value using `GET` in your php ?

Comment: Instead you can add `data :{category_id : "<?php echo $_GET['category_id']; ?> "}` in your ajax , then passed to your php and get it using `$_POST['category_id']`

Comment: Or if you don't care whether the category id comes from get or post, you can use `$_REQUEST['category_id']`

Comment: @Swati, @Philip Weinke Thank you very much for your help. It works. I added: `filter.php`, `var category_id = "<?php echo $_GET['category_id']; ?> ";` `fetach_data.php` `$category_id = $_REQUEST['category_id'] ?? '';`

Comment: @Philip Weinke Can you explain why `POST` and `GET`  doesn't work.

Comment: @Philip Weinke My mistake I checked wrong `POST` - works.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

**filetr.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data(1);

    function filter_data(page)
    {
        //$("#preloader").show();
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var filter_category = get_filter('filter_category');
        var filter_material = get_filter('filter_material');
        var filter_source_light = get_filter('filter_source_light');
        var filter_dimming_options = get_filter('filter_dimming_options');
        var filter_color_temperature = get_filter('filter_color_temperature');
        var filter_degree_tightness = get_filter('filter_degree_tightness');
        var category_id = "<?php echo $_GET['category_id']; ?> ";
        
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",   
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, filter_category:filter_category, filter_material:filter_material, filter_source_light:filter_source_light, filter_dimming_options:filter_dimming_options, filter_color_temperature:filter_color_temperature, filter_degree_tightness:filter_degree_tightness, page:page, category_id:category_id},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);       
            }
        });
    }
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'] ?? '';

if(isset($_POST["action"])) {
    
    $sql1 = "SELECT * ";
    $sql1 .= "FROM photographs ";
    $sql1 .= "WHERE category_id='" . $database->escape_string($category_id) . "' ";
```